# How to select all the 'not' part against the 'in' set in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Here is the problem:
I've got a set **A**: (1,2,3,4,5), and a mysql table **B** which looks like:

```
| id |
  1
  2
  3
  6
  7
```

What I want is to select all the elements in A which are not in the table **B**'s `id` field. Thus, the result should be (4, 5).

I've tried `select * from B where id not in (1,2,3,4,5)`, obviously, the result would be (6, 7).

I just can't get it through how to achieve what I intend to do. Could anyone give me some idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is only one row in table A with comma separated value?

Comment: Please, clarify what are you trying to achieve. You wrote that u want to select all the elements A (is A a table?) and below you write select from table B.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do and what you tried for that?

Comment: I think my sql not support reverse function of GROUP_CONCAT. Hope best way to you can achieve this is create procedure or function.

Comment: As I said, A is just a **set**, you could also think of that as just a string. **NOT** a table.

Comment: Think the only way to do this is to put the values from set A into some kind of table (either a generated one with from a series of UNION clauses) or by manually creating a temp table with these values first. SQL is for checking sets of data and returning values from it. The values you have in set A are not a set of data.

Comment: cant u handle from ur code. loop the list and check id is exists or not. If its some thing difficult to do sure you have to write mysql function or procedure. pass ur id list parameter, loop it return not exist ids which has in ur parameter list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using prepared statement. This requires many queries but I think it's a clean solution(IMO).

I am using it in a stored procedure where I get list of comma saperated customer ids and retrieve customer information.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempSplitValues;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempSplitValues(tempText TEXT);
SET @insertStatement = CONCAT('INSERT INTO tempSplitValues VALUES', REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT('(', REPLACE("1,2,3,4,5", ',', '), ('), ')'), '(', '("'), ')', '")')); -- Build INSERT statement like this -> INSERT INTO customerIdsTable VALUES("cusId1"),("cusId2")       
PREPARE stmt FROM @insertStatement; -- parse and prepare insert statement from the above string 
EXECUTE stmt; -- execute statement
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; -- release the statement memory

SELECT * FROM tempSplitValues tsv WHERE tsv.tempText NOT IN(SELECT id FROM B);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use left join instead - it's much more effective.

```
SELECT A.* FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```

First - left join records from table B, then filter by B.ID IS NULL - which means table A rows, that doesn't have corresponding records in table B.

Comment: A is just a set of number, not a table. Any alternatives?

Answer (score -1):

There's only two options I can see and neither is particularly elegant (I'd love to see better solutions though).

The first is to use unions to generate the list of numbers:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 1 AS id UNION SELECT 2 AS id UNION SELECT 3 AS id UNION SELECT 4 AS id UNION SELECT 5 AS id) AS a 
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM B);
```

This is pretty hideous however. The second option is to create a temporary table for A and use one of the other answers.

Comment: @Judking Then the second alternative would be better.

Comment: This will be a frequent dynamic operation, creating a temporary table is somewhat not what I want. Nevertheless, thanks anyway!