# Opposite function of find_in_set in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT find_in_set("1","1,2,3,4,5"); //return 1
```

Is there any function in mysql that can return non matching value from set of value like

```
SELECT find_in_set("1","1,2,3,4,5");
```

> Expected output is : 2,3,4,5

Help me If any function.

Comment: Can you explain what is the exact requirement? I mean why do you want that result.

Comment: Following POST for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671821/how-to-select-all-the-not-part-against-the-in-set-in-mysql/24671983#24671983 I ask question

Answer (score 4):

As per my knowledge, i dont think there is any function exist in mysql that gives you result except given input.

But, You can get what you want by doing this..

you can modify it as per your requirement.

**SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE NOT find_in_set("1","1,2,3,4,5");**

Comment: I want only using mysql is it possible?

Comment: I have just modified my answer above.... plz. try this, i am sure that this will work... @Sadikhasan

Comment: You are nearest my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to find multiple values like `NOT find_in_set("1,3,2","1,2,3,4,5");`

Comment: for that you would have to write you query like this..

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE NOT find_in_set("1","1,2,3,4,5") AND NOT find_in_set("2","1,2,3,4,5"); and so on......

Comment: There is not fix howmany numbers are there for search parameter?

Comment: If you want to do this only in sql then i dont think it is possible.
but, by using variable which will serve as search parameter,  could be poissible.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `replace()`:

```
select replace(concat(',', '1,2,3,4,5', ','), concat(',', '1', ','), '')
```

This puts delimiters at the beginning and end of both lists so `10` won't be confused with `100`.  If this isn't a problem, then you don't need the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it by using SUBSTRING_INDEX.

But make sure to put "," before and after the value otherwise it will split by value which is available in different position i.e if look for 12 it will also split where value is 123.

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX("11,22,33,44,55", ',22,', 1), ",",  SUBSTRING_INDEX("11,22,33,44,55", ',22,', -1));
```

If you are fine with this solution then you should create a function eg. FIND_NOT_IN_SET and pass two params and return final string.

I also posted another answer on [How to select all the 'not' part against the 'in' set in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671821/how-to-select-all-the-not-part-against-the-in-set-in-mysql/24675043#24675043) using prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using a series of UNIONed constants instead of a single value and a comma separated field:-

```
SELECT a.i
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5
) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 1 i
)
ON a.i = b.i
WHERE b.i IS NULL
```

Or if only ever 1 value you are looking for:-

```
SELECT a.i
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5
) a
WHERE a.i != '1'
```